# PhpStorm debugger breakpoint at variable use

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, breakpoints

Is it possible to set a "PHP Exception Breakpoint" inside of PhpStorm debugger so that it triggers each time a specific variable is used?

For example I have a `$_GET['foo']` in request and want debugger to pause every time the variable `$_GET['foo']` is used in code.

Comment: Nope. AFAIK none of the debuggers supported by PhpStorm (xdebug & zend debugger) support such kind of breakpoints. You can put conditions on breakpoints but not auto-break on certain variable access.

Comment: A "breakpoint at variable use" is called a **watchpoint**. JetBrains' CLion IDE [does support watchpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/using-watchpoints.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exception breakpoints only trigger when an error has occurred, so the short answer is "no."

However, you can right-click (or control+click, for Mac) the top folder in your source tree in the project file browser and choose "Find in Path" to locate all instances of `$_GET['foo']`.  Once you know where they all are, create normal breakpoints in the usual way.  Then put them into a "group," according to your intentions for those breakpoints:

1. Create breakpoints everywhere `$_GET['foo']` is referenced, using the **"Find in Path..."** feature of the project file browser to search for them globally (Find the main folder of your project; then *Right-click* for PC or *[Control]+[Click]* for Mac to find this option).
2. Once your breakpoints are set everywhere you find `$_GET['foo']`, click **Run > View Breakpoints** to show them in a list.
3. Select all of the corresponding breakpoints using *[Command]+[Click]* or *[Shift]+[Click]* to select multiple entries, if necessary.
4. *Right-click* or *[Control]+[Click]* your group of selected breakpoints in the list (or just an individual breakpoint, if you like) and choose **Move to group.**  If you do not have any groups made up yet, just choose **Create group** to make a new one.

In the **View Breakpoints** screen, you can then enable or disable the entire breakpoint group by checking its box.  When that group and its breakpoints are no longer needed, you can delete a group by clicking the [-] minus button.

Comment: I see. And thanks for mentioning the grouping feature.